# Why did the Apollo 16 crew wait until Station 8 to sample ray material from South Ray (instead of earlier during EVA 2)?

Tags: geology, crater, apollo-16

During EVA 2 on Apollo 16, the crew planned to sample material from an ejecta ray from South Ray crater at Station 8. Earlier during that EVA, the mission plan had them drive through a continuation of the same ray (Charlie Duke actually [points that out at 143:45:55 GET in the lunar surface journal transcript](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a16/a16.trvsta4.html#:%7E:text=you%20that.%20(Pause)-,143%3A45%3A55,-Duke%3A%20Boy%2C%20it%27ll)).

My question: **Why was Station 8 the preferred location to sample this ejecta ray? The lunar surface journal (comment below the [146:38:15 timestamp](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a16/a16.trv6to8.html#:%7E:text=big%20boulders%2C%20John%3F-,146%3A38%3A15,-Young%3A%20Call%20that)) specifies that they expected to find large boulders around that station. Was it because it was closer to the originating impact site (South Ray crater)?**

For reference, here's a rough draft of the EVA 2 traverse with my annotations in yellow (the arrow indicates where they traversed the continuation of the ray they sampled at Station 8):

[image]